# Forums Table Ranking Help (PHP / HTML)

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-table

I've recently created a forum with a table that displays data.

```
<div class="invis">
<div class="topic-top">
<table width="100%"><tr>
<td width="54%" style="color:white;">Topic</td>
</table>
</div>
<div class="topic-test">
<?php
while($thread=mysql_fetch_assoc($forum)){
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><a href='threads?id=".$thread['id']."'
     class='btn'>".$thread['title']."</a></td><hr>";
echo "</tr>";
}
?>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

When it displays data, it goes oldest first (by id). How do I make it display newest first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use MySQL to sort by ID in your query. You can read more about the order by clause [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/order_by.php).

```
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Use `ORDER BY id ASC` to sort the opposite way.

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm!